# Make ListViewItems Share Space Equally

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a vertical ListView, with one column. I have an ItemTemplate to draw my ListViewItems. Currently, each ListViewItem takes the minimum space required. I want them to take the maximum space available, so they share the available space equally between them. How do I do this?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Thanks! Know anything about ListViews? :)

Comment: That's up to the template. Post it, at least the outer XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the trick was to change the ItemsPanel of the ListView.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1"></UniformGrid>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```